# Discord.Net sending audio with ffmpeg only works once (the first time)

Tags: c#, audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, discord.net

### Context:

So I am writing a small bot that should play local audio files on command. I am using Discord.Net, ffmpeg, opus and libsodium.
I have a Speak() function that should, in Theory,

Open ffmpeg **->** encode .mp3 **->** create PCM stream **->** pump the encoded .mp3 to the output(PCM Stream).

That looks like this:

```
public async Task Speak(IGuild guild, Sound.SoundName soundName)
{
  IAudioClient client;
  if (ConnectedChannels.TryGetValue(guild.Id, out client))
  {
    using (var ffmpeg = CreateStream(sound.Filename))
    using (var stream = client.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Voice, 98304))
    using (var output = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream)
    {
     try
     {
       await output.CopyToAsync(stream);                            
     }
     catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Error " + ex.Message); Console.WriteLine($"- {ex.StackTrace}"); }
     finally { await stream.FlushAsync(); }
     Console.WriteLine("Spoken!");
   }
}

private Process CreateStream(string _path) 
{
  var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                 {
                   FileName = "ffmpeg",
                   Arguments = $"-hide_banner -loglevel panic -i \"{_path}\" -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
                   UseShellExecute = false,
                   RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                 });
  return process;
}
```

And it does this, but only one time. A bit more specific, When my bot joins a Voice Channel, it saves the VoiceChannel ID and the IAudioClient in a `private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, IAudioClient> ConnectedChannels = new ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, IAudioClient>();`. After that it automatically calls the Speak() function to play a hello.mp3 audio. This Process is done like this:

```
[Command("join", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
[RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.MentionEveryone)]
public async Task JoinChannel(IVoiceChannel channel = null) 
{
 // Get the Voice channel
 channel = channel ?? (Context.User as IGuildUser)?.VoiceChannel;
 if (channel == null) { await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You are not in a VoiceChannel"); return; }

 // Saving the AudioClient
 var audioClient = await channel.ConnectAsync();
 Console.WriteLine($"Connected to channel {channel.Name}");

 ConnectedChannels.TryAdd(channel.Guild.Id, audioClient);

 await Task.Delay(1000);
 await Speak(Context.Guild, Sound.SoundName.hello);
}
```

This works pefectly fine, The audio plays.

Now that the bot is connected to a VoiceChannel and the IAudioClient is saved to the Dictionary. I should be able to call the Speak() function whenever i want and from Whereever i want, as long as the bot is in the VoiceChannel, right?

**No it doesnt.**

and that takes me to my

### Problem:

After the bot is now sitting silently in the voice channel i call a "speak" command that looks in code like this:

```
[Command("speak")]
public async Task speakSingle() 
{
  await Speak(Context.Guild, Sound.SoundName.Random);
}
```

But the bot remains silent, even though the speak indicator in Discord lights up! What am I missing? I dont get it. Is it sending an empty stream?
Even when I disconnect the bot from the VoiceChannel an reconnect it It wont send audio. The only thing that helps is Reconectiong the Bot From the Server.
 I am pretty new to C# and Streams and async programing. So could somebody help me out finding the problem and fix it?

### Errors (CommandPromt Ouput):

1# 
This occures when i run the "speak" command, im getting a NullReferenceException for "Discord.WebSocket.pdb not loaded" in VisualStudio. Allthough I couldn't find anything thats null...

```
17:34:17 Audio #1    System.Exception: WebSocket connection was closed
 ---> Discord.Net.WebSocketClosedException: The server sent close 4008: "Rate limited."
   at Discord.Net.WebSockets.DefaultWebSocketClient.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Discord.ConnectionManager.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<<StartAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

2# 
This occures when the bot rejoined the Voice Channel and automatically executes the Speak() function.

```
Error A task was canceled.
-    at Discord.Audio.Streams.BufferedWriteStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Discord.Audio.Streams.OpusEncodeStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Bot.Modules.VoiceChannel.Speak(IGuild guild, SoundName soundName) in Y:\Dokumente\Coding\C#\Vs_Studio\Bot\Bot\Modules\VoiceChannel.cs:line 90
```

This is my first Question on StackOverflow and i hope i provieded enough context, if not tell me please.

Comment: Have you considered using Lavalink? You run the lavalink server jar and can use a .NET Lavalink wrapper such as Victoria.Lavalink or Lavalink4NET to connect to it. Lavalink can be configured to take audio from a range of sources, including local files. The libraries I listed above are built to work with Discord.NET, and Lavalink is used by the most popular music bots such as Rythm.

Comment: @230Daniel I have heard about Lavalink but thought that it was only used to get music from web links like youtube. I will give it another look . Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @230Daniel So I got lavalink running with victoria.Lavalink but i cant get local files to play. Do you know how to load local files ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but hopefully this helps anyone looking for a solution.

The problem seems to be with when the CreatePCMStream is disposed you are not able to create a new one until you reconnect the bot to the voice channel, I'm not sure if this is a bug with discord .net or just how the discords api works.

What I ended up doing was storing the AudioOutStream in a ConcurrentDictionary after the first call of the speak method, then on bot disconnect disposing of the audio stream and remove it from the ConcurrentDictionary.

This fixed the issue of playing multiple audio files without having to disconnect the bot from the voice channel.